# find values of k that makes it have solutions, no solutions or infinite amount of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Linear Algebra

This was the original question system presented

$x  −  2y  +  4z  =  6$

$x  +  y  +  z  =  k$

$2x  −  y  +  5z  =  k^2$

I got it reduced down to

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &  2&-2k+18 \\ 
 0& 1 &  -1& 6-k \\ 
0 & 0 & 0& 3k^2-k-30
\end{bmatrix}

in matrix form

But I don't know how to continue on to find whether or not it has solutions, no solutions or an infinite amount of solutions

Comment: $3k^2 -k -30 = 0$ implies that $k=-3$ or $k=10/3$. I’m pretty sure the other two are true no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you meant the system resolves to this:
$$
\\
[A|b]=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &2  &-2k+18 \\ 
 0& 1 &-1  & 6-k\\ 
 0&0  &0  &  3k^2-k-30
\end{bmatrix}_{REF}$$

A matrix representing a system of equations makes no sense with $x$ in the matrix.

For **unique solutions**, $\text{rank}[A|b]=\text{rank}[A]=3$.

The easiest way to find the rank of a matrix is to count the number of **non-zero rows when in REF**.

We see $[A]$ always has a rank of two, so we never have unique solutions.

For **infinite solutions**, $\text{rank}[A|b]=\text{rank}[A]<3$.

We can see through that as $\text{rank}[A]=2$, so for $\text{rank}[A|b]=2\Rightarrow 3k^2 -k-30=0$.

For **no solutions**, $\text{rank}[A|b]>\text{rank}[A]$.
This will occur for any $k$ value where $0\neq3k^2-k-30.$

Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 0):

From the reduced matrix form, it can be seen that the system will have solution if,
$$ 3k^2-k-30=0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the reduced matrix form derived is not quite  correct. Add the first two equations

$$x  −  2y  +  4z  =  6$$
$$x  +  y  +  z  =  k$$

to get

$$ 2x -y +5z = k+6$$

which is ‘parallel’ to the third equation,

$$2x  −  y  +  5z  =  k^2$$

So, the system either has no solution or infinite number of number of solutions.

For infinite number of solutions, the right-hand-sides of the two equations above are equal,

$$k+6=k^2$$

So, $k$ takes the $k=3,\>\>\>k=-2$ for the system of equations to have infinite solutions. Otherwise, there are no solutions.